# Basic foundation for a physics engine using SFML and Dear ImGui

Tags: c++, c++20, sfml

I want to create a very basic physics engine in [SFML](https://www.sfml-dev.org). I also want to be able to control objects using [Dear ImGui](https://github.com/ocornut/imgui). So I created this basic foundation. My main problem with it is how I handle rendering the GUI, because I couldn't find another way to implement it, either just drawing an object, or drawing object and a GUI. Mainly because the draw function must be `const`.

This is supposed to be able to handle both objects that have a GUI (`IEntityWithGui`) and those that don't (`IEntity`). But in this example there's just objects with a GUI.

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include "imgui/imgui.h"
#include "imgui/imgui-SFML.h"
#include "updater.h"
#include "renderer.h"
#include "shapeObj.h"

int main() {

    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200, 200), "PhysicsBox");
    ImGui::SFML::Init(window);
    sf::Clock clock;
    std::atomic<bool> isRunning{ true };

    ShapeObj shape{window};

    Renderer render{ &window,isRunning };
    render.queueSubmit(&shape);

    Updater update{ &window,isRunning,std::ref(clock) };
    update.queueSubmit(&shape);

    window.setActive(false);
    window.setKeyRepeatEnabled(false);

    update.startThread();
    render.startThread();

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            ImGui::SFML::ProcessEvent(event);
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed) {
                isRunning.store(false);
                render.joinThread();
                update.joinThread();
                window.setActive(true);
                window.close();
            }
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Resized)
            {
                // update the view to the new size of the window
                sf::FloatRect visibleArea(0.f, 0.f, event.size.width, event.size.height);
                window.setView(sf::View(visibleArea));
            }
            shape.eventProcess(event, clock.restart());

        }


    }
    ImGui::SFML::Shutdown();

    return 0;
}
```

IEntity.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
class IEntity : public sf::Drawable, public sf::Transformable
{
public:
    virtual void update(sf::Time dt)=0;
    virtual void eventProcess(sf::Event event,sf::Time dt)=0;
    virtual ~IEntity(){}
};
```

IEntityWithGui:

```
#pragma once
#include "IEntity.h"
class IEntityWithGui : public IEntity
{
public:
    virtual void processGui()=0; 
    virtual ~IEntityWithGui() {}
};
```

shapeObj.hpp:

```
#pragma once
#include "IEntityWithGui.h"

class ShapeObj : public IEntityWithGui
{
public:
    ShapeObj(sf::RenderWindow &window);

    virtual void draw(sf::RenderTarget& target, sf::RenderStates states) const override;
    virtual void update(sf::Time deltaTime) override ;
    virtual void processGui() override;
    virtual void eventProcess(sf::Event event, sf::Time time) override;
    virtual ~ShapeObj()=default;
private:
    sf::CircleShape m_shape{ 100.f,75 };
    sf::RenderWindow& m_window;
    bool m_show_gui = false;
    bool m_mouse_captured = false;
};
```

ShapeObj.cpp:

```
#include "shapeObj.h"
#include "imgui/imgui.h"
#include "imgui/imgui-SFML.h"

ShapeObj::ShapeObj(sf::RenderWindow& window)
    : m_window(window) {};

void ShapeObj::draw(sf::RenderTarget& target, sf::RenderStates states) const
{
    states.transform *= getTransform();
    target.draw(m_shape, states);
}

void ShapeObj::update(sf::Time deltaTime)
{
    //It will be used, just not now. 
}

void ShapeObj::processGui()
{
    if (!m_show_gui) return;
    ImGuiIO io = ImGui::GetIO();
    ImGui::SFML::Update(m_window, sf::seconds(1.f / 60.f));
    ImGui::Begin("Grid");
    if (io.WantCaptureMouse) {
        m_mouse_captured = true;
    }
    else {
        m_mouse_captured = false;
    }
    ImGui::Text("Mouse captured=%d\n",
        m_mouse_captured);
    ImGui::End();
    ImGui::SFML::Render(m_window);
}

void ShapeObj::eventProcess(sf::Event event, sf::Time time)
{
    auto mousePos= m_window.mapPixelToCoords(sf::Mouse::getPosition(m_window));

    if (!m_mouse_captured) {
        if(event.type==sf::Event::MouseButtonPressed &&
           m_shape.getGlobalBounds().contains(mousePos))
        {
            m_show_gui = !m_show_gui;
        }
        //Whatever other events
    }
}
```

threadWithQueue.h:

```
#pragma once
#pragma once
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>

template <class T>
class ThreadWithQueue {
public:
    ThreadWithQueue<T>(sf::RenderWindow* window, std::atomic<bool>& isRunning);
    void startThread();
    void joinThread();
    virtual void queueSubmit(T object);

protected:

    virtual void queueThread()=0;
    std::atomic<bool>& isRunning;
    sf::RenderWindow* m_window;
    std::thread mThreadObj;
    std::vector<T> m_queue;
};

template <class T>
ThreadWithQueue<T>::ThreadWithQueue(sf::RenderWindow* window, std::atomic<bool>& isRunning)
    : m_window{ window }, isRunning{ isRunning } {}


template <class T>
void ThreadWithQueue<T>::startThread() {
    mThreadObj = std::thread{ &ThreadWithQueue::queueThread,this };
}
template <class T>
void ThreadWithQueue<T>::joinThread() {
    if (mThreadObj.joinable()) {
        mThreadObj.join();
    }
}
template <class T>
void ThreadWithQueue<T>::queueSubmit(T object) {
    m_queue.push_back(object);
}
```

updater.h:

```
#pragma once
#include "threadWithQueue.h"
#include "IEntity.h"


class Updater : public ThreadWithQueue<IEntity*> {
public:
    Updater(sf::RenderWindow* window, std::atomic<bool>& isRunning, sf::Clock& global_clock);
    ~Updater() = default;
private:

    virtual void queueThread();
    sf::Clock& m_global_clock;
};
```

updater.cpp

```
#include "updater.h" 
Updater::Updater(sf::RenderWindow* window, std::atomic<bool>& isRunning, sf::Clock& global_clock)
    : ThreadWithQueue<IEntity*>(window, isRunning), m_global_clock(global_clock) {}

void Updater::queueThread() {
    while (isRunning.load()) {
        for (auto& i : m_queue) {
            i->update(m_global_clock.restart());
        }
    }
}
```

renderer.h:

```
#include "updater.h" 
Updater::Updater(sf::RenderWindow* window, std::atomic<bool>& isRunning, sf::Clock& global_clock)
    : ThreadWithQueue<IEntity*>(window, isRunning), m_global_clock(global_clock) {}

void Updater::queueThread() {
    while (isRunning.load()) {
        for (auto& i : m_queue) {
            i->update(m_global_clock.restart());
        }
    }
}
```

renderer.cpp:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include "renderer.h"
#include "imgui/imgui.h"
#include "imgui/imgui-SFML.h"
Renderer::Renderer(sf::RenderWindow* window, std::atomic<bool>& isRunning)
    : ThreadWithQueue(window,isRunning) {}


void Renderer::queueThread() {
    m_window->setActive(true);
    while (isRunning.load()) {
        m_window->clear();
        for (auto& i: m_queue) {
            m_window->draw(*i);

        }
        for (auto& i : m_queue_gui) {
            m_window->draw(*i);
            i->processGui();
        }


        m_window->display();
    }
    
}

void Renderer::queueSubmit(IEntityWithGui* object)
{
    m_queue_gui.push_back(object);
}
```

Comment: It looks like you forgot to include renderer.h, and instead pasted a duplicate of updater.cpp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are using C++20, consider using [`std::jthread`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/jthread/jthread) instead of `std::thread`; it will remove the code for `threadWithQueue`. **`std::jthread`** automatically `join`s as part of its destruction. You can also get rid of the `atomic` variable(`isRunning`), using [`jthread::request_stop` method](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/jthread/request_stop).
Your `m_queue` is totally decoupled from the threading logic, so you may even totally drop the `threadWithQueue` and provide `m_queue` as a parameter to your thread functions.
Another important issue is using `m_window` in 3 different threads without proper synchronization. Adding mutexes can degrade your GUI performance and not synchronizing the threads just results in UB and surprising outputs. You need a lock-free mechanism in the rendering(**soft realtime**) thread to ensure smooth graphical experience. On the other hand, your event loop must actually initiate update actions in the updater thread. So you need another synchronization system(preferably lock-free) between event loop and updater thread. In short that means at least two `atomic` flags or other synchronization objects. I don't delve into detail now, because of the number of design decisions involved in determining them.